# Angular: Promise dependant on other promises in routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-routing

I'm a little confused when it comes to promises in Angular (or in general) and I just can't get this one to work the way I want it.

I can't share the code I'm working with but here's some mockup code:

```
var personModule = angular.module('personModule', [], ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/person/:personId/cars',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/personCars.html',
        controller: 'personCarsController',
        resolve: {
            'person': resolvePerson,
            'cars': resolveCars
        }
    });
}]);

function resolvePerson($route, personFactory){
    var personId = $route.current.params.personId;

    return personFactory.getPerson(personId).then(function(response){
        return angular.fromJson(response).data;
    });
}

function resolveCars($route, personFactory, carFactory){
    var personId = $route.current.params.personId;

    return personFactory.getPersonCars(personId).then(function(response){
        var cars = angular.fromJson(response).data;

        angular.forEach(cars, function(car){
            carFactory.getModel(car.modelId).then(function(response){
                car.model = angular.fromJson(response).data;

                carFactory.getMaker(car.model.makerId).then(function(response){
                    car.model.maker = angular.fromJson(response).data;
                });
            });
        });

        return cars;
    });
}
```

The data format for cars will be something like this in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "year": "1992",
        "color": "red",
        "modelId": 1,
        "model": 
        {
            "name": "Corolla",
            "makerId": 1,
            "maker":
            {
                "name": "Toyota"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "year": "1998",
        "color": "black",
        "modelId": 1,
        "model": 
        {
            "name": "Escort",
            "makerId": 2,
            "maker":
            {
                "name": "Ford"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Now the code above works just fine. It's just that when I click on the link to open the page the data comes with a delay as the promises resolve. The routing waits for person and cars to resolve but not for the model and maker for each car, which is what I would like to happen. I've strolled through all Angulars documentation on promises and defers and I'm just at a loss right now.

**EDIT:**

```
function resolveCars($route, personFactory, carFactory){
    var personId = $route.current.params.personId;
    var promises = [];

    return personFactory.getPersonCars(personId).then(function(response){
        var cars = angular.fromJson(response).data;

        angular.forEach(cars, function(car){
            promises.push(carFactory.getModel(car.modelId).then(function(response){
                console.log("Resolving model");
                car.model = angular.fromJson(response).data;

                promises.push(carFactory.getMaker(car.model.makerId).then(function(response){
                    console.log("Resolving maker");
                    car.model.maker = angular.fromJson(response).data;
                }));
            }));
        });

        return $q.all(promises).then(function(){
            console.log("Resolved");
            return cars;
        });
    });
}
```

Changed the code as suggested and now it waits for the carModel to resolve but not for the carMaker.

Console output for one car is this:

```
Resolving model
Resolved
Resolving maker
```

**EDIT 2:**

Solved it :) Changed the

```
promises.push(carFactory.getMaker(car.model.makerId).then(function(response){
    console.log("Resolving maker");
    car.model.maker = angular.fromJson(response).data;
}));
```

part to

```
return carFactory.getMaker(car.model.makerId).then(function(response){
    console.log("Resolving maker");
    car.model.maker = angular.fromJson(response).data;
});
```

Thanks for the help! I knew my original code wouldn't work like I wanted it to but couldn't for the life of me figure out how I should change it.

Comment: `var cars = angular.fromJson(response).data;` Why do you do this?

Comment: personFactory.getCars(personId) returns a promise from a $http call which then returns a JSON string of the cars. The .data part confuses me as well as I don't need that in controller but in route resolving I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because the routing is resolved, as soon as the promise is resolved, that you define in your 'resolve' property of the route.

In your resolveCars Function you do resolve the cars and then inside you start your background "resolveModels" function. Nevertheless, 'cars' is resolved and you do return it. The background task won't stop the promise from resoling.

Your could return another promise, that will resolve only, when the models of all cars are resolved.

You could do something like this:

```
function resolveCars($route, personFactory, carFactory, $q) {
    var personId = $route.current.params.personId;

    return personFactory.getPersonCars(personId).then(function (response) {
        var cars = angular.fromJson(response).data;
        var promises = [];
        var deferred = $q.defer();


        angular.forEach(cars, function (car) {
            var modelWithMakerPromise = carFactory.getModel(car.modelId).then(function (response) {
                car.model = angular.fromJson(response).data;
                return car.model;
            }).then(function (model) {
                return carFactory.getMaker(model.makerId).then(function (response) {
                    model.maker = angular.fromJson(response).data;
                });
            });
            promises.push(modelWithMakerPromise);
        };
        $q.all(promises).then(function () {
            defered.resolve(cars);
        });
        return defered.promise;
    });
```

This is not tested, but should work and give you an idea.
Basically I create a new promise that i return. This promise will only resolve, when all those carModel Promises do resolve.
Have look at [$q Api Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

regards

Comment: I think you need another return - `return carFactory.getMaker(...)`. Also, the need to create/resolve a your own Deferred can be avoided with `return $q.all(promises).then(function() { return cars; };`

Comment: Thank you! Now it waits for the model but still not for the maker. I have updated the question with the new code if you would be so kind and check it out :)

Comment: Basically it was the same issue, I started a background  "give me the maker of that car" process in the "car.model"-resolve function, that was not part of the overall resolving:
I edited my answer, to reflect your problem.
Basically I chained the "car.model-promise" to the "model.maker-promise".
So the promise will only resolve, when all chained promises are resolved.
Hope it works